# Find objects with similar properties and are adjacent to each other

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with properties theaterID and price, I want to add the prices together if the objects have the same theatherID and are adjacent to each other.

```
[{theatherID: 1, price: 10.0}, {theatherID:1, price: 15.0}, {theatherID:55, price: 2.0}, {theatherID:1, price:3.0}]
```

The output should be

```
[{theatherID: 1, price: 25.0}, {theatherID:1, price: 25.0}, {theatherID:55, price: 2.0}, {theatherID:1, price:3.0}]
```

Comment: Have you tried any solution? Written any code? Have you considered using map() function?

Comment: What do mean by adjacent to each other?

Comment: @ChetanRaikwal Adjacent as in elements that are separated by one index.

Comment: @EmmanuelNK I have tried to create an empty object and use the property I want to observe as the key and an array of indexes as the value. I then loop through the properties in the object and then the values of the properties and subtract the indexes to see if their difference is equal to 1. I was hoping to find a more elegant answer.

Comment: In that case I can think of sorting the entire array by theatreId and then in a single iteration sum all prices untill any theatherID changes. Lodash had methods that can achieve it in less complexity.

Comment: But ya being adjacent to each other will require to maintain the order, so maybe can't use sorting I guess.

Comment: This type of problem reminds me of the sliding window technique https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = [{theatherID: 1, price: 10.0}, {theatherID:1, price: 15.0}, {theatherID:55, price: 2.0}, {theatherID:1, price:3.0}];

for(i=0; i<x.length-1; i++){
 if (x[i].theatherID == x[i+1].theatherID){
   var tmp = x[i+1].price;   
   x[i+1].price += x[i].price;
   x[i].price += tmp;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for the array method [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).  It takes a function with two parameters and executes once for each element in your array.

On the first pass `prev` is equal to whatever you pass as the second argument in `reduce`, in this case it will be an empty array.  The parameter `next` is equal to the `i`th element of your array.  (on the first pass it is the first element, second pass is the second, etc.)

So as the `reduce` function passes through the array, you can check to see if `next` has a theatherID that matchest the latest element in `prev`.  If it does, update both `price` properties and add `next` to the array we are building (`prev`).

```js
var arr = [{theatherID: 1, price: 10.0}, {theatherID:1, price: 15.0}, {theatherID:55, price: 2.0}, {theatherID:1, price:3.0}];

var newArr = arr.reduce((prev, next) => {
  var latest = prev[prev.length - 1];
  if(latest && latest.theatherID === next.theatherID) {
    var total = latest.price + next.price;
    latest.price = total;
    next.price = total;
  }
  prev.push(next);
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```